# how to join an associated table with a has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I only require users to enter email and name upon signup, but then give them the option to provide fuller contact details for their profile. Therefore, I have a User.rb model that has an association with Contact.rb, namely,

User.rb

```
 has_one :contact
```

Contact.rb

```
 belongs_to :user
```

Contact.rb has the predictable fields you might expect such as address, postal code etc, but it also stores the province_id for a relation with the Province.rb model, so

Contact.rb

```
 attr_accessible :address, :city, :mobile,  :postalcode, :province_id, :user_id
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :province
```

Province.rb

```
has_many :contacts
```

I did it that way (rather than storing the name of the province as a "string" on contact.rb) so that I could more easily (so I thought) categorize users by province.

In the show action of one of the artists_controller, I do the following to check whether the user is trying to sort by province and then call an artists_by_province method that does a search

```
    if params[:province_id]
     province = params[:province_id]
     province = province.to_i #convert string to integer

     @artistsbyprovince = User.artists_by_province(province)

     else

     @artists = User.where(:sculptor => true)

     end
```

This is the method on the User.rb model that it calls if a province id is passed in

```
scope :artists_by_province, lambda {|province|
  joins(:contact).
  where( contact: {province_id: province},
         users: {sculptor: true})

  }
```

However it gives me this error:

```
Could not find table 'contact'
```

If I make contacts plural

```
scope :artists_by_province, lambda {|province|
  joins(:contacts).
  where( contacts: {province_id: province},
         users: {sculptor: true})

  }
```

This error

```
Association named 'contacts' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong when I'm making this query?

Update: I changed some of the details after posting because my copy and paste had some problems with it

P.S. ignore the fact that I'm searching for a 'sculptor.' I changed the names of the user types for the question.

from schema.rb

```
create_table "contacts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "firm"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "postalcode"
    t.string   "mobile"
    t.string   "office"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
    t.integer  "province_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem was fixed  by using `contact` (singular) in the join and `contacts` (plural) in the where clause. I'm guessing 'contact' (singular) reflects the has_one association between User.rb and Contact.rb, whereas 'contacts' is used in the where clause to represent the name of the table, which is always plural.

User.rb

```
  has_one :contact

  scope :artists_by_province, lambda {|province|
  joins(:contact).
  where( contacts: {province_id: province},
         users: {sculptor: true})

  }
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I understand too. By the way, my post is of no use for you since it will generate the province_id condition on the left join clause resulting to all users with sculptor = true.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
scope :artists_by_province, lambda {|province|
  joins(contact: {province: { id: province}}).
  where(sculptor: true)
}
```

Comment: that gave me this error: Association named 'province_id' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with this. Is your solution better than mine? If so, can you explain why? Thanks.

Comment: Yours is the valid one. Try them both in a console to see the difference.