# Rails 5: How to query the parent array from a child array in a has_one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Devise table that has become bloated so I decided to split it into a User and UserDetail table.

```
Before: User table
| ID | Username | Gender

- @girls = User.where(gender: "female")
- @girls.each do |g|
  = link_to g
```

Now, I don't know the proper way to get the parent arrays from the child array or vice versa and their elements, so I just do it like this:

```
After: User table: has_one :user_detail
| ID | Username

After: User Detail table: belongs_to :user
| ID | User_ID | gender

- @girls = UserDetail.where(gender: "female")
- @girls.each do |g|
  - @user = User.find_by_id(g.user_id)
  = link_to "#{@user.username}", user_path(@user)
```

Is there a better way to get the parent array from the child array and vice versa in the controller instead of the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
@girls = User.joins(:user_detail).where(user_details: {gender: 'female'})
 @girls.each do |g|
  = link_to "#{g.username}", user_path(g)
```

Notice the joins has the name of the relationship but the where the name of the table, so the first is singular and the second plural.

```
#g.username is a g.user_details.gender
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way in your case is using `joins`

```
@girls = User.joins(:user_detail).where(gender: "female")
- @girls.each do |g|
  = link_to "#{@user.username}", user_path(@user)
```

Answer (score 0):

I joined Kushanir's answer to this one:
[how to join an associated table with a has_one association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349195/how-to-join-an-associated-table-with-a-has-one-association)

and got the following to work:

```
@girls = User.joins(:user_detail).where(user_details:{gender: "female"})
```

But I found out that the queries were a bit slower if I split the User Details into another table, so I 'm staying with an unsplit Devise Users table.